# SQL Code Check Integration with Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, syntax

I have downloaded the SQL Code Check from the below link and integrated it with the Visual Studio Professional 2015
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MAQSoftware.SQLCodeCheck

When I try to execute(See Screenshot) the SQL Code Check > Execute SQL Code Check , the Output window does not show anything.

I do not understand whether  everything correct in the SQL code or SQL Code Check is not working properly.
[image]

Comment: The Output tab says "Should output from: Build" ... what other options are in that list?

Comment: I build the other solution the output screen showed the build succeeded message.Then i again try to execute the SQL Code check for the code in image.The output screen was still showing the previous build  succeeded message.I think the output window is not following my instruction of executing the SQL Code check.The  "Should output from: Build" goes empty list when I am trying now. Yesterday it was from Build.